# Why Do I Still Get a Duplicate Entry Error When There is No Duplicate Entry?

Tags: mysql, errors, duplication

I am trying to insert this data into my database: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjQflI82acM3dFI1Mk04dWlYSFJtM0hsZ0g4ZlExMWc&usp=sharing

I receive the following error: `1062 - Duplicate entry 'MLS' for key 'MLS'`

I have searched for all `MLS` field values from this sheet in the table I am trying to import into but there are no matches.

Why am I still getting this error?

**UPDATE:** Ok, so I don't know why this allowed me to successfully import my data but I was able to do  this by editing the `.csv` in Sublime Text 2 and adding a line break to the end of the sheet. Then when I imported it I checked the `Do not abort on INSERT error` box.

I guess my revised question is why did this fix my issue?

**UPDATE:** @Maxime here is the result of running `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_realty_listingsdb;`: http://pastebin.com/8nWPAWYJ

Answer (score 0):

The error refers to the field name and the key name (not the value).

You should have a `UNIQUE KEY` on the field `MLS`, can you paste the result of:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTable;
```

Max.